# Normal distribution in every segment, what is the final distribution?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

Suppose a ball start at $x=\mu$ when $t=0$; when $t=1$, the ball's coordinate distribution satisfies $N(\mu, \sigma^2/N)$; Suppose the ball's coordinates is at $x=x_1$ at $t=1$, then the ball's coordinate distribution satisfies $N(x_1,\sigma^2/N)$ when $t=2$;$\cdots$ the same idea goes on, question: **what is the distribution at $t=N$?** In the limit of $N\to\infty$, the answer is lognormal distribution, but I don't know how to derive it.

Here is my try, the PDF of $X_2$ is:

$$
f_2(X=x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2/N}}e^{-(x-x_1)^2/(\sigma^2/N)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2/N}}e^{-(x_1-\mu)^2/(\sigma^2/N)} dx_1
$$

This integral can be done, but the following deduction seems more and more complex...

Comment: Hint: see [Brownian Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge) processes. Not a complete answer but a start.

Comment: Are $x_1,...,x_n$ independent? Are they fixed or random?

Comment: Your description sounds like a Brownian Motion, but then the limiting distribution is Normal, not Lognormal.  Your assertion that it is Lognormal suggests you might not have stated the problem as clearly or accurately as you intended.  Could you clarify it?

Comment: Did you actually try to solve the integral? The solution may give you a hint.

Comment: @whuber Will it still be a Brownian motion if in every segment, the variance is different?

Comment: The variance of what, exactly? The standard definition requires stationary increments, which implies the variance of the *increments* (if it exists at all) is constant. But this also implies that the variance of the *values* increases linearly with time.